# threads for the question, as more conclusions, comments are made

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Instead of just commenting under the answer, it will be helpful to create a thread by the person who raised the question, in order to imply the steps of conclusion drawn with the help of the comments by peers ! in that way, it is seen , all the comments are valuable and helpful in drawing the conclusion for the question raised

Comment: It seems to me that you think about this as a "normal forum", but it's not a forum. It's a Q&A site. Comments are not first-rate citizens.

Answer (score 5):

The underlying philosophy of the Stack Exchange Network is that it is a questions and answers site.  The goal is to have a database of good questions with high quality answers.  The questions and answers are primary---everything else on the site serves to improve the quality of the questions and answers.  The intended use for comments is to request clarification.  Indeed, the expectation of the creators of the site is that comments will be deleted once the suggested changes are made to a post.  As such, comments are "second class citizens" on the network.  The lack of threading is *by design*, and is unlikely to be changed.